Sprinkler Pump Outdoor Plug with Relay
We recently bought a home that had a shed, which we removed. The shed housed a run of cable to a sprinkler pump at the back of the property. It also housed the pump start relay. The shed is now gone and I have dug the trench to reconnect the power back to the pump. My plan is to put a pedestal next to the pump and attach the receptacle and relay there. See pics.
I have a few concerns:
The pump has a receptacle connection. It is a 20 amp 230v pump. Can I install an outdoor receptacle, plug the pump in, and reliably expect it to work while exposed to the elements? I have never used an in-use outdoor receptacle cover before.
I have read that GFCI is not recommended in this instance. Why is that?
Same thing with the relay. Will the relay be okay exposed to elements? I know they are weather resistant boxes, and I plan to build a sort of roof over the pedestal.


Put Snoopy's Doghouse or a lighthouse or an old-style Dutch Windmill over them - less ugly and some weather protection. Properly grounded there should be little risk from not using a GFCI on it, though I'd be inclined to try it with, myself.

Building a roof over the pedestal will help. The weatherproof covers and relay work well in most conditions. There may be a breaker trip in extreme weather.
Around our condo building the in-use outdoor covers work great for the plug in fountains. No problems  the relay boxes for the well pumps are fine as well.
The pump start draw would probably cause the GFI to open that is why it is not recommended.

Make sure the pump itself is rated for outdoor use. Or put that too inside a "mini-shed" enclosure to keep rain off it.
